# Java Assertions, in comparison/contrast to Unit Tests and Exceptions

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, assert

Here's my high-level, general question:

***Why would one use Assertions as opposed to Unit Tests and Exception Handling?***

To clarify my confusion and qualify my concerns, I'll talk a bit about what I know of Java Assertions and my background insofar as is pertinent to this line of questioning.

So, to start, before this week, I honestly didn't even know about the Java framework's assertions, nor their function, so I absolutely admit that I'm likely not getting the whole picture.  That being said, I have been a professional in web development, data, and API development for almost a decade now, so I'm not entirely naive.

From what I've read, and discussions I've had, assertions are generally used during development, (almost) always turned off in production, and will check for post conditions and class invariant values; they can be and are used for other things, but these two things seem to be their main contemporary usage.  They are built on top of the Java Exceptions, are a subtype of `Error`, and are thrown when violated.  When turned off, they add no runtime overhead.

To me, however, they seem superfluous, especially when considering good Exception handling techniques and good unit testing practices.  I fail to see any circumstance where an assertion would alert the programmer to a bug or issue that exception handling or unit testing would not.

Following that line of thought, they seem to me to create code clutter.  If they are not meant to be run in production and act as a development aid, then their presence in production code is a bit of an anti-pattern: you have separate source folders for tests and test resources, and you write testable code, rather than code strictly for testing.  Whenever I find myself writing code just so I can test, that alerts me to poor design, and I step back and re-architect what I'm doing so that my code is testable.  It seems to me that this is an example of that paradigm being violated.  Wherever an assertion exists, it could be replaced by a try/catch block, if/then/else with an appropriate exception being thrown, or by a set of unit tests - at least, that's the way it seems to me.  Having assertions in production code, that will not be run during production, is confusing.  It also distracts from the purpose of the code and what the code's doing.  I find that a test that would evaluate the same condition an assertion would to be immensely more readable, since it'd be contained in a test that could be named and documented for that exact scenario.

Can others add insight to this train of thought?  Perhaps you agree - add examples why or expound upon my reasoning.  Then again, maybe you think I'm very wrong - state why and provide examples to back up your reasoning, or provide counter-arguments to the way I view things.

Thanks all!

---

Resources I've consulted, for your reference:

- http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoNotUseAssertions
- http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/06/asserions-in-java-assertions-vs.html
- http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=102
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html

Comment: In general, you might be right. You could write a JUnit test for each "testing" `assert` and you could replace each "functional" `assert` with a `try-catch` block or a `throw`. But for quick code sampling, it is easier to write an `assert` than writing a complete test case. Maybe that is the niche of Java's `assert` keyword...

Comment: "for quick code sampling, it is easier to write an assert than writing a complete test case" - is one more correct than the other, or do they simply have different/complementing use cases?  it seems to me that a unit test would be more correct from the perspective that there's a clear separation of test and production code, and that explicit throwing of a detailed and aptly named exception would be clearer and more readable.  am i just quibbling at this point?

Comment: This is exactly what i meant with *quick code sampling*. Unit tests are more elaborate and more expensive to code, as well as `try-catch` blocks and propper exception handling.

Answer (score 2):

Using assertions, one should cover conditions that are believed to be *impossible* to occur. It is preferable to die aloud when impossible happen over continuing and providing incorrect results or unrelated exception at some latter point. Unit tests are not really an alternative as you can not use them to prove some conditions can *not* occur.

One of the typical uses is the `switch` statement. If you are confident that all the possible states are covered by `case` clauses, you can keep the `default` block empty and hope you ware right (and you will still be right when surrounding code changes) or put an assertion there so you will be notified in case you ware wrong.

Whether you decide to use Java's `assert` statement (that can be turned off as you said) or throw `AssertionError` directly (which is something that can not be turned off) is entirely up to you.

Comment: "Unit tests are not really an alternative as you can not use them to prove some conditions can not occur" - I think this is one concept that I'm not grasping.  How would an assertion prove that a certain condition cannot occur, where a unit test couldn't?  And in regards to the switch statement, why wouldn't I want to throw an InvalidArgumentException, etc. explicitly, as opposed to an assert, which would presumably be turned off in production?

Comment: I am not saying you can prove something can never happen (or something will always happen) using assertions. I suggest to express such assumption using assertion so it can be disproved in a visible way (compared to a log message or a comment).

Comment: Java's `InvalidArgumentException` says client passed invalid value to your code. Though it does not make sense in case those values come from your own code because of programming error.

Comment: Note that the concept of enforcing invariants through compilation/runtime failures goes far beyond java and its assertions. The fact those can be turned off in JVM is irrelevant.

Comment: One nice feature of assert is that you can have as many as you want with no runtime cost in production environments.  Generous use of assert can identify issues during development and QA simply by running the code with "-ea".  When running in production, do not enable assertions, and the code to test the condition will not even be compiled by JIT.

Answer (score 2):

This topic is about opinions, so I just add few thoughts that I have about that topic. Those does not cover all the aspects but it can complement others' opinions.

Sometimes I use asserts just to express that I made some assumptions when writing a code. Simple example: I call method to obtain value that in general can be `null` e.g. find user by name but in this particular situation this can't happen because e.g. I am in the middle of his registration. Therefore I skip the "null check" in code but I want to make clear to whom ever will read my code afterwards (maybe me in one month :)) that I have considered this option

```
User user = findUser(userId);
assert user != null : "we are in the middle of registration"
user.confirmEmail();
```

Clearly, I can use simple comment to do so, but is not much worse when it comes to cluttering of the code.

Second use-case is, as you already mentioned, checking of invariants. "School example" would be the situation that you are implementing merge sort and during the merge phase the algorithm expects that both subarrays you want to merge are already sorted (by previous steps).

Clearly, you would implement unit tests that will check if the sorting works well, but this can verify only "end to end" correctness. That's fine for most of the situations, but as you are implementing it, you find out that one of your tests is failing. Unfortunately, this test uses "big input" and all your "simple" tests are passing, so it is impractical for you to debug the problem. As the merge class has no state and works only with recursion and local variables, you can't introspect the state from the outside unit tests. This is the place where you can use asserts to check the internal invariants. And once the invariant fails, you get the stacktrace (so you find out that there is a problem in the 4th level of recursion) and you can add the actual state of important local variables to the message so it can help you identify the circumstances of the error. Asserts here are good since you don't want to "recheck" if subarrays are sorted during the production as such checks can be quite expensive.

Once you fix the code, you might be tempted to remove such code, but this can depend on the situation. Why do we write unit tests in first place? Because if we make refactoring, we want to be sure if we haven't break anything. And if you expect that you might want to refactor the code and the invariants you made could remain, you might want to keep them for future. Otherwise you can simply delete them or don't use asserts at all and just use some temporal code to find the issue.

Comment: "Clearly, I can use simple comment to do so, but is not much worse when it comes to cluttering of the code."  I can see this point.  My initial inclination would be to disagree, but stepping back, I can see that as a function of documentation, you're right.  I guess insofar as comments are concerned, it's just a matter of getting used to seeing an assert as a (type of) comment, at least in certain circumstances.